# Responsive table with overflow-x: auto and overflow-y: visible not working

Tags: html, css

I have the following code which doesn't work as I want it to:

```
<div style="overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: visible">
table....
</div>
```

The idea is that the table should display scroll for X to make it responsive, this part works. The problem is that witin the tabe I have items that you can hover over which display additional information and when you do hover over it it actually creates a Y scroll. I don't want that, I want the hover over box with information to be visible without creating a scroll Y. Does someone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: can you please provide a codepen or similar with the full example. Thanks

Comment: I believe [this](https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/) article is what you need. hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately this is quite bad, might need to use JS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421966/css-overflow-x-visible-and-overflow-y-hidden-causing-scrollbar-issue